# Is there any other third-party library available besides react-native-document-scanner?

Tags: android, react-native, document, barcode-scanner

I need a document scanner in my android app but react-native-document-scanner doesn't work for me.
Is there any other free third-party document scanner library available?

Comment: First of all welcome to StackOverflow.
As a new user this site can be a bit intimidating.
(we have quite strict quality control, unlike other sites).
Be prepared for brutal analysis of your questions ! 
Please take a moment to see the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),(you get a badge for looking at it!).
SO is a mostly user monitored site.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know whether it is still relevant for you, but here is an article guiding you through the integration of the scanning function for a React Native app with little code using the Docutain Scanner SDK. There is a free trial option and demo to test it:
[create-a-react-native-document-scanner](https://sdk.docutain.com/blogartikel/how-to-create-a-react-native-document-scanner)